# Construction heater in garage

Tags: electrical

I would like to run an underground wire from my driveshed to my garage to run a 4800 watt construction heater. I think they draw 20-25 amps.  I don't have 220 in the garage. The distance is 200 ft. Is 10/2 UF wire heavy enough for that distance?

Comment: thanks for the replies , just to clarify I already have 110 in the garage , lights and receptacles . New line is just for heater

Comment: What's the make and model of the heater?  Is it hardwired, or cord connected?

Answer (score 3):

4800w @ 220V 21.81A. 10AWG is two small.  8 awg is right on the edge using 3% max voltage drop (uglys page 50) if you want to run any lights you should be using 6AWG for that long of a run.

Comment: Ed has this right. Although, your residential voltage should be ~240 volts, still, his calculation for #8 wire is correct.  Here is a handy calculator for voltage drop. http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm entering your parameters and a 3% drop yields #8 wire.

Comment: What size breaker should be used?

Comment: @Tester101 - wouldn't that depend on what the heater nameplate or instruction manual specifies (if hardwired), or the receptacle type if it's plug in? If it's a NEMA 6-30, that would imply a 30A breaker.

Comment: I like the calculator link ArchonOSX provided. way faster than looking up and calculating... :)

Answer (score -3):

no.  that is not heavy enough wire for what you want to do.

Comment: What would the correct size be?

Comment: 30A would be the next larger size since it draws +21A